# How to set environment variable for C# with java and python already installed?

Tags: c#

How to set environment variable for C# when path is already set for Java and Python in my system?

Comment: are you compiling c# from command line?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get/set it.

```
string path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine) + ";c:\\";
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", path, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```